# multiple url link variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

`index.php?dc=downloads&dl=all&sort=id` shows all downloads, and sorts by id

inside of downloads.php it GETs the variables `dl` and `sort` to query MySQL accordingly, to
display the tables on downloads.php

I have the links `Show <a href="index.php?dc=downloads&dl=all">All</a>`, tools, etc that set the `dl` variable to display certain tables

but now, I want to be able to set another variable `sort` when the user clicks on one of the sort links from the list, without it resetting the `dl` variable

`Sort by <a href="index.php?dc=downloads&sort=id>id</a>` wouldn't work because it would reset `dl`

Comment: Post your code so we can see what may be wrong with it based on what you have above said.

Comment: there is no code, except the links `Show <a href="index.php?dc=downloads&dl=all">All</a>` that set the `dl` and `sort` variables, I want to know how to set both of them without resetting the whole url

Comment: 2 ways, either place `&dl=all` to your sort url and vice-versa for the `sort=id` or use sessions to store the selections the user made to reuse it as you please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few ways of doing this, but the easiest way, given the code you have supplied, is just to input the current `$_GET['dl']` value.  Like so:

```
<a href="index.php?dc=downloads&sort=id&dl=<?=$_GET['dl']?>" >id</a>
```

`<?=$_GET['dl']?>`: This will take the `dl` value that is currently in the get parameters and place it into your link.

A better method would probably be to check if there is already a `dl` value in the GET parameters first:

```
<? if(isset($_GET['dl']) && $_GET['dl'] != ''): ?>
    <a href="index.php?dc=downloads&sort=id&dl=<?=$_GET['dl']?>">id</a>
<? else: ?>
    <a href="index.php?dc=downloads&sort=id">id</a>
<? endif; ?>
```

This way, you wont end up with a link like `index.php?dc=download&sort=id&dl=` if `dl` hasn't yet been set.